# Loading and saving numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having troubles loading a numpy matrix. I successfully saved it to disk through:

```
self.q.dump(fileName)
```

and now I want to be able to load it. From what I understand, the load command should do the trick:

```
self.q.load(fileName)
```

but it seems not. Anyone knows what might be wrong? Maybe the function is not called load?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving and loading a Numpy Matrix in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848099/saving-and-loading-a-numpy-matrix-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
help(numpy.ndarray)

 |  dump(...)
 |      a.dump(file)
 |      
 |      Dump a pickle of the array to the specified file.
 |      The array can be read back with pickle.load or numpy.load.
 |      
 |      Parameters
 |      ----------
 |      file : str
 |          A string naming the dump file.
```

`numpy.load` should work fine.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't. AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load'

Comment: @d.e.: I'ts not a method on an array, it's a function. Be sure to call it like `numpy.load(filename)`, not `q.load(..)` (where q is an array).