# Save Numpy Array using Pickle

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I've got a Numpy array that I would like to save (130,000 x 3) that I would like to save using Pickle, with the following code. However, I keep getting the error "EOFError: Ran out of input" or "UnsupportedOperation: read" at the pkl.load line. This is my first time using Pickle, any ideas?

Thanks,

Anant

```
import pickle as pkl
import numpy as np

arrayInput = np.zeros((1000,2)) #Trial input
save = True
load = True

filename = path + 'CNN_Input'
fileObject = open(fileName, 'wb')

if save:
    pkl.dump(arrayInput, fileObject)
    fileObject.close()

if load:
    fileObject2 = open(fileName, 'wb')
    modelInput = pkl.load(fileObject2)
    fileObject2.close()

if arrayInput == modelInput:
    Print(True)
```

Comment: fileobhect2 should be opened for read, not write

Comment: I'm confused, what are the pros/cons of `pickle vs np.save/z` etc?

Comment: did any of the solutions here help you? If not do you mind clarifying what was wrong with them? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439701/how-to-save-and-load-numpy-array-data-properly

Answer (score 59):

You should use [numpy.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [numpy.load](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load).

Comment: Upvoting.  `pickle` is good for arbitrary python data.  `np.save` and `np.load` will be *much* more efficient for numeric data.

Comment: I can't test it now, but I thought `save` was  the numpy pickling method.  Conversely `save` uses pickle to write non array elements.

Comment: as suggested, please have a look at complete sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60208983/5437090)

Comment: can you comment what is wrong with using pickle please? thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps a comment on `np.save` vs `np.savez` would be helpful.

Comment: Tried using save/load for numpy.ndarrays and they always came back empty.  Urgh.

Comment: @piokuc can you elaborate, why using numpy.save and load are better than pickle?

Answer (score 29):

I have no problems using `pickle`:

```
In [126]: arr = np.zeros((1000,2))
In [127]: with open('test.pkl','wb') as f:
     ...:     pickle.dump(arr, f)
     ...:     
In [128]: with open('test.pkl','rb') as f:
     ...:     x = pickle.load(f)
     ...:     print(x.shape)
     ...:     
     ...:     
(1000, 2)
```

`pickle` and `np.save/load` have a deep reciprocity.  Like I can load this pickle with `np.load`:

```
In [129]: np.load('test.pkl').shape
Out[129]: (1000, 2)
```

If I open the pickle file in the wrong I do get your error:

```
In [130]: with open('test.pkl','wb') as f:
     ...:     x = pickle.load(f)
     ...:     print(x.shape)
     ...:    
UnsupportedOperation: read
```

But that shouldn't be surprising - you can't read a freshly opened write file.  It will be empty.

`np.save/load` is the usual pair for writing numpy arrays.  But pickle uses `save` to serialize arrays, and `save` uses pickle to serialize non-array objects (in the array).   Resulting file sizes are similar.  Curiously in timings the pickle version is faster.

Comment: I'm confused, what are the pros/cons of `pickle vs np.save/z` etc?

Comment: seems the pickle library won't work unless one uses the `b` bytes for read `rb` when loading and writing `wb` when saving, right? Without it I get this error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Answer (score 13):

It's been a bit but if you're finding this, Pickle completes in a fraction of the time.

```python
with open('filename','wb') as f: pickle.dump(arrayname, f)

with open('filename','rb') as f: arrayname1 = pickle.load(f)

numpy.array_equal(arrayname,arrayname1) #sanity check
```

On the other hand, by default numpy compress took my 5.2GB down to .4GB and Pickle went to 1.7GB.

Comment: basically the main advantage of using pickle vs numpy.save/z is that numpy is optimized to use less space when saving? is that right?

Comment: I wonder if your comment of storage efficiency only applies to `np.save` or it also applies to `np.savez`

Answer (score 8):

Don't use pickle for numpy arrays, for an extended discussion that links to all resources I could find see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62883249/1601580).

Short reasons:

- there is already a nice interface **the developers of numpy** made and will save you lots of time of debugging (**most important reason**)
- `np.save,np.load,np.savez` have pretty good performance in most metrics, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41425878/1601580), which is to be expected since it's an established library and the developers of numpy made those functions.
- Pickle executes arbitrary code and is a security issue
- to use pickle you would have to open and file and might get issues that leads to bugs (e.g. I wasn't aware of using `b` and it stopped working, took time to debug)
- if you refuse to accept this advice, at least really articulate the reason you need to use something else. Make sure it's crystal clear in your head.

Avoid repeating code at all costs if a solution already exists!

Anyway, here are all the interfaces I tried, hopefully it saves someone time (probably my future self):

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('~/data/tmp/').expanduser()
path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

lb,ub = -1,1
num_samples = 5
x = np.random.uniform(low=lb,high=ub,size=(1,num_samples))
y = x**2 + x + 2

# using save (to npy), savez (to npz)
np.save(path/'x', x)
np.save(path/'y', y)
np.savez(path/'db', x=x, y=y)
with open(path/'db.pkl', 'wb') as db_file:
    pickle.dump(obj={'x':x, 'y':y}, file=db_file)

## using loading npy, npz files
x_loaded = np.load(path/'x.npy')
y_load = np.load(path/'y.npy')
db = np.load(path/'db.npz')
with open(path/'db.pkl', 'rb') as db_file:
    db_pkl = pickle.load(db_file)

print(x is x_loaded)
print(x == x_loaded)
print(x == db['x'])
print(x == db_pkl['x'])
print('done')
```

but most useful see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62883249/1601580).

Comment: I'm using a library that embeds numpy arrays inside of python objects, but I need to store data along the way.  Seems like using pickle is preferable in this case so a person does not need to deconstruct the entire library in order to save the numpy arrays with save and the rest with pickle.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of extra possible ways. Sometimes you should add extra option `protocol`. For example,

```
import pickle

# Your array
arrayInput = np.zeros((1000,2))
```

Here is your approach:

```
pickle.dump(arrayInput, open('file_name.pickle', 'wb'))
```

**Which you can change to:**

```
# in two lines of code
with open("file_name.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(arrayInput, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

or

```
# Save in line of code
pickle.dump(arrayInput, open("file_name.pickle", "wb"), protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Aftermath, you can easy read you numpy array like:

```
arrayInput = pickle.load(open(self._dir_models+"model_rf.sav", 'rb'))
```

Hope, it is useful for you

Answer (score 2):

Many are forgetting one very important thing: ***security***.

Pickled data is binary, so it gets run immediately upon using `pickle.load`. If loading from an untrusted source, the file could contain executable instructions to achieve things like man-in-the-middle attacks over a network, among other things. (e.g. see [this realpython.com article](https://realpython.com/python-pickle-module/#security-concerns-with-the-python-pickle-module))

Pure pickled data may be faster to save/load if you don't follow with bz2 compression, and hence have a larger file size, but `numpy` load/save may be more secure.

Alternatively, you may save purely pickled data along with an encryption key using the builtin `hashlib` and `hmac` libraries and, prior to loading, compare the hash key against your security key:

```py
import hashlib
import hmac

def calculate_hash(
    key_,
    file_path,
    hash_=hashlib.sha256
):
    with open(file_path, "rb") as fp:
        file_hash = hmac.new(key_, fp.read(), hash_).hexdigest()

    return file_hash

def compare_hash(
    hash1,
    hash2,
):
    """
    Warning:
        Do not use `==` directly to compare hash values. Timing attacks can be used
        to learn your security key. Use ``compare_digest()``.
    """
    return hmac.compare_digest(hash1, hash2)
```

In a corporate setting, always be sure to confirm with your IT department. You want to be sure proper authentication, encryption, and authorization is all "set to go" when loading and saving data over servers and networks.

**Pickle/CPickle**

If you are confident you are using nothing but trusted sources and speed is a major concern over security and file size, `pickle` might be the way to go. In addition, you can take a few extra security measures using `cPickle` (this may have been incorporated directly into `pickle` in recent Python3 versions, but I'm not sure, so always double-check):

1. Use a `cPickle.Unpickler` instance, and set its "find_global" attribute to `None` to disable importing any modules (thus restricting loading to builtin types such as `dict`, `int`, `list`, `string`, etc).
2. Use a `cPickle.Unpickler` instance, and set its "find_global" attribute to a function that only allows importing of modules and names from a whitelist.
3. Use something like the `itsdangerous` package to authenticate the data before unpickling it if you're loading it from an untrusted source.

**Numpy**

If you are only saving `numpy` data and no other `python` data, and security is a greater priority over file size and speed, then `numpy` might be the way to go.

**HDF5/H5PY**

If your data is truly large and complex, `hdf5` format via `h5py` is good.

**JSON**

And of course, this discussion wouldn't be complete without mentioning `json`. You may need to do extra work setting up encoding and decoding of your data, but nothing gets immediately run when you use `json.load`, so you can check the template/structure of the loaded data before you use it.

**DISCLAIMER:** I take no responsibility for end-user security with this provided information. The above information is for informational purposes only. Please use proper discretion and appropriate measures (including corporate policies, where applicable) with regard to security needs.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `numpy.save()` for saving numpy matrices.

Comment: I'm confused, what are the pros/cons of `pickle vs np.save/z` etc?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're using

```
if load:
    fileObject2 = open(fileName, 'wb')
    modelInput = pkl.load(fileObject2)
    fileObject2.close()
```

The second argument in the `open` function is the method. `w` stands for writing, `r` for reading. The second character `b` denotes that bytes will be read/written. A file that will be written to cannot be read and vice versa. Therefore, opening the file with `fileObject2 = open(fileName, 'rb')` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to `save` and `load` a NumPy array -

```
# a numpy array

result.importances_mean
array([-1.43651529e-03, -2.73401297e-03,  9.26784059e-05, -7.41427247e-04,
        3.56811863e-03,  2.78035218e-03,  3.70713624e-03,  5.51436515e-03,
        1.16821131e-01,  9.26784059e-05,  9.26784059e-04, -1.80722892e-03,
       -1.71455051e-03, -1.29749768e-03, -9.26784059e-05, -1.43651529e-03,
        0.00000000e+00, -1.11214087e-03, -4.63392030e-05, -4.63392030e-04,
        1.20481928e-03,  5.42168675e-03, -5.56070436e-04,  8.34105653e-04,
       -1.85356812e-04,  0.00000000e+00, -9.73123262e-04, -1.43651529e-03,
       -1.76088971e-03])

# save the array format - np.save(filename.npy, array)

np.save(os.path.join(model_path, "permutation_imp.npy"), result.importances_mean)

# load the array format - np.load(filename.npy)

res = np.load(os.path.join(model_path, "permutation_imp.npy"))
res
array([-1.43651529e-03, -2.73401297e-03,  9.26784059e-05, -7.41427247e-04,
        3.56811863e-03,  2.78035218e-03,  3.70713624e-03,  5.51436515e-03,
        1.16821131e-01,  9.26784059e-05,  9.26784059e-04, -1.80722892e-03,
       -1.71455051e-03, -1.29749768e-03, -9.26784059e-05, -1.43651529e-03,
        0.00000000e+00, -1.11214087e-03, -4.63392030e-05, -4.63392030e-04,
        1.20481928e-03,  5.42168675e-03, -5.56070436e-04,  8.34105653e-04,
       -1.85356812e-04,  0.00000000e+00, -9.73123262e-04, -1.43651529e-03,
       -1.76088971e-03])
```